# How to set up dynamic custom hostname by its replica using `docker-compose`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is only for development purposes, I just want to able to read my hostname properly.

What I want is basically this.

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu:21.10
    tty: true
    hostname: ubuntu_$replica
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
```

The `$replica` above is based on the `replicas`. So later on when I access the server one by one. The hostname should be `ubuntu_1`, `ubuntu_2`, `ubuntu_3`

I've been trying to google this up, but I might be using the wrong keyword. If this isn't possible with Docker then feel free to tell me too.

Comment: How about replace your `$replica` with `{{.Task.Slot}}`. This should be possible but I'm worry it will work only on Swarm mode. You can check the placeholder section in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/

Comment: In the [standard Compose networking setup](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) each container is accessible by its Compose service name (`ubuntu`) and also its container name; the standard generated Compose container names will be like `project_ubuntu_1`, where `project` is the name of the directory holding the Compose file.  `hostname:` isn't used for this at all.  Are the Compose-provided defaults good enough for you?

Comment: @TruongHua the problem is I haven't got the chance to learn about that yet, and I just want to do a simple replica of it.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes I know that, thank your for the `project` part, I didn't acknowledged that since I haven't used Docker again for a while. However I was just wondering if this kind of stuff possible, so I can clearly read where I'm at in the terminal. It's for convenience reason that's all.